# Does the RecyclerView recycle Bitmaps stored within ImageViews

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-recyclerview, recycle

I am trying to track down a bug where an ImageView is using a recycled Bitmap, my question is will the RecyclerView automatically recycle my Bitmaps when the ViewHolder is recycled?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Viewholder is intended to prevent the extra resources for findViewByid look ups. i dont think it does anything extra than that!